# Hosting videos for use in Flowplayer (pseudostreaming)?

Tags: web-hosting, video

Flowplayer's pseudostreaming plugin requires a specific server configuration to work.

https://static.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html

What video services/hosts/CDNs exist that offer support for pseudostreaming?  Which do you use/recommend?

In case it's relevant, I intend to host H.264-encoded MP4s. No livestreaming.

Comment: Don't use H.264 use WebM. Why pay royalty when WebM is free and everyone but Safari supports it. http://www.webmproject.org/

Comment: H.264 is royalty free if you're just posting videos on your site. And while support for WebM is upcoming, many many more softwares and devices support H.264. And don't forget for the same bitrate, H.264 is significantly higher quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Amazon S3 can handle it. If not, you can setup whatever you want with EC2. Also, there is this:

http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/cdn.html